# How to save $index from ng-repeat to array itself

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a shopping cart.

The "add to cart" function is something like this (abbreviated):

```
    "add" : function(code) {
            codes.push({
                "id"            : code.id,
                "order"         : "N/A",
                "name"          : code.name,
                "code"          : code.code,
                "image"         : code.image,
                "custom_made"   : 0,
                "quantity"      : 1
            });
            this.store();
        }
    }
```

Right now I'm implementing an option to let clients reorder their items in their basket. I'm using [ui-sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable) for that. This works great. Clients drag and drop their products to achieve the order they desire.

But now I need to save that order to the array of products itself.

I need to get the `$index` the `ng-repeat` directive uses and save it with a similar function to the above, except I save the `$index` to the `code.order` object.

How would I achieve something like that? I've been looking around but find no way of getting the `$index` outside the `ng-repeat` directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [ui-sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable) plugin specifically for Angular. As items are re-ordered, the model will automatically be updated.

Comment: The OP mentions in the question that he's using ui-sortable, so this doesn't really answer anything.

Comment: That's true, I'm using that plugin, but it completely slipped my mind that the plugin itself could have that possibility, which it has, as can been seen here: http://codepen.io/thgreasi/pen/iKEHd